# Can I mix linux-based and windows-based containers in same docker engine host?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm using **Docker Desktop for Windows** with the new feature of Windows Containers now Windows-based containers are possible but it raised this question?

Can I mix **linux-based** and **windows-based** images in same docker engine host?
If yes, are going to work all network features?
Is this independent of the host OS for the user?

Comment: It's still not possible to mix the two containers (Windows and Linux) but it is now possible to run Linux containers on W2016: [Linux Docker container on Windows Server 2016](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42978854/444244)

Comment: I strongly advise against this, if you intend to communicate containers from different platforms. It literally took me a week to solve different weird errors with this, before finally giving up this design.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You will need a Linux to launch Linux containers and a Windows Server 2016 to launch Windows containers

I said in [Run normal Win32 applications in Docker for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572975/run-normal-win32-applications-in-docker-for-windows/35574780#35574780)

if you have Windows Server 2016, you will be able to launch Windows containers (and you will need a Linux server to launch Linux containers).

See those links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_docker

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/container_setup

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/containers_welcome

In Windows, your Dockerfile will start with

FROM windowsservercore

instead of the more usual

FROM debian or FROM ubuntu

See some examples of IIS in (Windows) docker

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_docker

or a SQL Server in docker

http://26thcentury.com/2016/01/03/dockerfile-to-create-sql-server-express-windows-container-image/

Comment: This is incorrect, Windows 2016 can run linux containers also.

Comment: yes recently, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011535/how-to-run-linux-docker-images-on-windows-server-2016 for example, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995973/linux-docker-container-on-windows-server-2016/42978854#42978854

Comment: @TuukkaLindroos Link please.